# Selenium locate <textbox> nested in <table td>

Tags: selenium, xpath, element

i want to select the specific textbox from a form based on its id attribute using selenium.

I tried this below code but its showing "unable to locate id..."  error.

```
WebDriverWait waitt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
waitt.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName")));

WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*  [@id='leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName']"));`
```

and also i tried like `WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName"));` but still no luck.

Is there anything in selenium to select nested textbox element ?

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140304-c1dk-105kb.jpg (Press CTRL + to zoom image)
Here(in image) is the html structure of my page.
In this image i have highlighted the textbox for which i am trying to target.

html code as suggested in comment below

```
<table id="page-container" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

 <tbody><tr>
    <td id="page-header">

<div id="top">

<div id="page-title" class="limiter clear-block">

<div id="header-top">

<div id="logo"><img id="logo-image" alt="Home" src="images/logo.png"></div>

<div id="header-right">

<div id="block-ad" class="block block-ad">

<div class="block-content clear-block ">



</div>

</div>



<div id="header-links">

<!-- added table for structure -->

<table style="display:block; float:right;" class="norubik" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tbody><tr>

<td align="center"><font color="#666"><a href="/user" style="color: red;font-size:10px;font-family:Verdana;color:#666;text-decoration: none">My Account </a> | <a style="color: red;font-size:10px;font-family:Verdana;color:#666;text-decoration: none" href="/logout">Logout</a></font></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center">

<span class="username"><!--Logged in as--> <strong>admin</strong>

<!-- Code for image -->

<div style="position:relative; top:2px; left:0px;">





    <img src="images/premier_small.png">







</div>

</span>

</td>

</tr>

</tbody></table>

</div> 









</div>

</div>

<div style="width: 100%; clear: both; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 6px; height:30px;">


<!-- begin menu div -->

<div class="AJXCSSMenuGdPbSLD"><!-- AJXFILE:ajxmenu.css -->

<div class="ajxmw">

<div class="ajxmw2">

<ul>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/" title="Home"><b>Home</b>

    </a>

    <div style="display: none;" class="ajxdd">

    <div class="ajxsbg">



    </div>

    </div>

    </li>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3111" title="Getting Started"><b>Getting Started</b>

    </a>


    </li>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/2962" title="Training"><b>Training</b>

    </a>

    <div style="display: none;" class="ajxdd">

    <div class="ajxsbg">



    <ul>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/faq" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3431" title="Video Tutorials">Video Tutorials</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3138" title="Training Webinars">Training Webinars</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/pub/training-schedule" title="Training Schedule">Training Schedule</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3735" title="Internet Marketing Webinars">Internet Marketing Webinars</a></li>



    </ul>



    </div>

    </div>

    </li>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/reseller/ir/leadCaptureList" title="Leads"><b>Leads</b>

    </a> 
    </li>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/2964" title="Affiliate"><b>Affiliate</b>

    </a> 

    </li>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/catalog/179" title="Store"><b>Store</b>

    </a>

    <div style="display: none;" class="ajxdd">

    <div class="ajxsbg">



    <ul>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/catalog/179" title="Memberships">Memberships</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/catalog/219" title="Marketplace">Marketplace</a></li>



    </ul>



    </div>

    </div>

    </li>



    <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/" title="Resources"><b>Resources</b>

    </a>

    <div style="display: none;" class="ajxdd">

    <div class="ajxsbg">



    <ul>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3017" title="Support">Support</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/reseller/calendar" title="Calendar/Events">Calendar/Events</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3440" title="Documents">Documents</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/17" title="Documents">Documents</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/reseller/ir/contactInfo" title="Upline Report">Upline Report</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3353" title="Feature Comparison">Feature Comparison</a></li>



        <li style="position: static;" class=""><a class="ajxsub" href="/node/3497" title="Developer (API)">Developer (API)</a></li>



    </ul>



    </div>

    </div>

    </li>







</ul>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<!-- end menu div --></div>

</div>



<div id="branding">

<div class="limiter clear-block">

<div class="breadcrumb clear-block"><span class="breadcrumb-link"><a href="/">LeadOutcome</a></span> <span class="breadcrumb-link"><a href="leadCaptureList.action">Leads</a></span> <span class="breadcrumb-link"><a href="leadCaptureList.action">Manage Leads</a></span>  </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>






    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td id="content-container">

        <div id="page" class="clear-block page-content">

    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-wrapper clear-block">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="bhdr-container"><span class="bhdr"> Manage Leads </span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<span style="color: blue; font-weight: bold"></span>
<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold"></span>


<form id="leadCaptureList" name="leadCaptureList" action="leadCaptureList.action" method="post">
<div><input name="advanceSearchClicked" value="No" id="advanceSearchClicked" type="hidden">

    </div><table class="wwFormTable">
    <input name="leadsToTransfer" value="" id="leadsToTransferId" type="hidden">
    <input name="deleteids" value="" id="leadCaptureList_deleteids" type="hidden">
    <input name="leadOrIR" value="Lead" id="leadCaptureList_leadOrIR" type="hidden">
    <input name="savedSearchCriteria.searchName" value="" id="leadCaptureList_savedSearchCriteria_searchName" type="hidden">
    <input name="savedSearchCriteria.published" value="" id="leadCaptureList_savedSearchCriteria_published" type="hidden">
    <input name="leadSearchName" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadSearchName" type="hidden">
    <input name="cfValuesFromSessOrDB" value="false" id="leadCaptureList_cfValuesFromSessOrDB" type="hidden">

    </table><table class="hdr-section-search" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table style="background-color: #F8F8F8" class="conbox4" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody><tr>

                    <th colspan="4"><font size="2">Search Options (Search criteria can be combined)</font></th>
                    <th colspan="6" align="right"> 
                        <select id="currentlyOwnedLeads" name="currentlyOwnedLeads">

                            <option value="All">All leads </option>

                            <option value="No">Show all leads ever owned by me </option>
                            <option value="Yes">Show only leads currently owned by me </option>
                        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input name="" value="All" id="currentlyOwnedIdUsedForJavascript" type="hidden">
                     <input name="coForManageLeads" id="selectedSalesRepCo" value="" type="hidden">
                    <input name="id" value="" id="leadCaptureList_id" type="hidden"> Sales Rep: <span id="selectedIrCompany"></span> <a href="javascript:void()" id="searchIrButton"><img src="images/btn_find_IR.png" border="0"></a></th>

                    <th colspan="3" align="center">
                     <span onmousemove="ddrivetip(receiveSummaryMouseover,150)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Receive Lead Summary:<select name="receiveLeadManagementSummaryEmails" id="summaryMailsField" onchange="setReceiveLeadManagementSummaryEmails();">
    <option value="false">No</option>
    <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>


</select>
 </span> 
                    </th>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Lead Id:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadIdForSearch" maxlength="7" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadIdForSearch" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>
                    <td align="right">First Name:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.firstName" value="test Lo" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>
                    <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.lastName" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_lastName" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>
                    <td align="right">Email:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.email" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_email" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>


                    <td align="right">Phone No.:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.phone" value="" id="phoneNo" style="width:80px" type="text"></td> 
                    <td align="right">Status:</td>
                    <td><select name="leadCapture.status" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_status">
    <option value="">-- Select Status --</option>
    <option value="New">New</option> 
    <option value="Converted">Converted</option>


</select>

                    </td>

                </tr>




                <tr id="advancedSearchRow1" style="display: none">
                        <td align="right">Company:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.company" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_company" style="width:80px" type="text">     </td>

                    <td align="right">Address:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.address" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_address" style="width:128px" type="text"></td>

                    <td align="right">City:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.city" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_city" style="width:122px" type="text"></td>
                        <td align="right">State:</td>
                    <td><select name="leadCapture.state" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_state">
    <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>



</select>

                    </td>
                        <td align="right">Zip Code:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.zip" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_zip" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr id="advancedSearchRow2" style="display: none">
                    <td align="right">Lead History:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.leadHistory" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_leadHistory" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>

                    <td align="right">Category:</td>
                    <td><select name="leadCapture.leadCategory.id" id="leadCategorySearch1" style="width:122px">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">All Leads</option>
    <option value="2">Business Leads</option> 
    <option value="200">Webinar Follow up 12/4</option>


</select>
</td>

                    <td align="right">Custom Field Type:</td>
                    <td><select name="leadCapture.leadTypeObj.id" id="leadTypeId" style="width:122px" onclick="disableLeadType()" onchange="showCustomFields();">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">-Select Type-</option>
    <option value="16">Contacts</option>
    <option value="139">ZMS: How can we help you?</option>
    <option value="178">Gita</option>
    <option value="206">111 test</option>


</select>
</td>


                    <td align="right">Interest :</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.interest" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_interest" style="width:80px" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">Score :</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <select name="scoreLogicalOperator" id="leadCaptureList_scoreLogicalOperator">
    <option value="greater" selected="selected">Greater than</option>
    <option value="less">Less than</option>
    <option value="equal">Equal to</option>


</select>

                    &nbsp;
                    <input name="serachByleadScore" value="" id="leadCaptureList_serachByleadScore" style="width:80px" type="text">
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr id="advancedSearchRow3" style="display: none">
                    <td align="right">Lead Source:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.leadSource" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_leadSource" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>

                    <td align="right">Ad Code:</td>
                    <td><input name="leadCapture.adCode" value="" id="leadCaptureList_leadCapture_adCode" style="width:80px" type="text"></td>

                    <td colspan="8" align="right"></td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="right" width="250px;">

                    <img src="images/btn_m_save_search.png" id="saveLeadSearchId" onclick="return popUpForSaveLeadSearch();" align="absmiddle" border="0">
                        <select name="savedSearchCriteria.id" id="leadCaptureList_savedSearchCriteria_id" onclick="disableLeadSearch()" onchange="return selectSearchCriteriaByName();">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">--Select a search--</option>


</select>
</td>
                    <td colspan="6"><input style="display: none;" value="Delete Search" onclick="return deleteLeadSearchData();" id="deleteSearchButton" type="button"></td>

                    <td id="tdForAdvancedSearch" align="right"><a href="javascript:advancedSearch()" id="advancedSearchLink"><img src="images/btn_m_show_advanced.png" border="0"></a>
                    </td>

                    <td colspan="3" align="right"><input alt="true" src="images/btn_search.png" id="leadCaptureList_searchBtn" name="searchBtn" value="true" onclick="$('#pageNumber').val(1);return validSearchField();" type="image">

                    &nbsp;<input alt="Submit" src="images/btn_m_clear_search.png" id="leadCaptureList_0" value="Submit" onclick="clearAllSearchFields();" type="image">
</td>

                </tr>


            </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <div id="customFieldsDiv"></div>
    <input name="noOfLeadsToBeDisplayed" value="250" id="noOfLeadsToBeDisplayedId" type="hidden">
    <input name="pagination" value="" id="pagination" type="hidden">
    <input name="pageNumber" value="1" id="pageNumber" type="hidden">
    <input name="backButton" value="false" id="backButton" type="hidden">
    <input name="nextButton" value="false" id="nextButton" type="hidden">
    <input name="saveSearchFlag" value="false" id="leadCaptureList_saveSearchFlag" type="hidden">

    </form></div>

</div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: any help , is this possible?  If my above question is not clear then please tell  me here

Comment: _Never_ post code as images. Nobody's able to reproduce anything like this. If the code is too large for putting it in the question, put the relevant parts in the question and everything else in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or wherever you'd like it to have.

Comment: A textbox with an id attribute will not make a difference whether it's a nested or non-nested element. Is the textbox visible when the page gets rendered? Or is it dynamic?

Comment: @JensErat okay performing what you suggested...

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar I think so for that purpose i even tried checking `WebDriverWait waitt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
  waitt.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName")));`  But still the same error. & text box is not dynamic. The same code was running in my localsystem on regural firefox  but i am getting this issue when i uploaded this on linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a textbox which has an id attribute should practically not fail. Selenium WILL find it if it's there. In case if the element is not present / visible in the DOM when the findElement command gets executed then Selenium will throw an exception.

You can try WebDriver explict wait like this and see if it works:

```
  WebElement textBox = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName")));
```

Comment: In the generated html code i saw this text-box id has been loaded and visible. But why its not selecting. any suggestion?